# What does AXE. and MCE. before a weapon or spell mean?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My bound sword spell is listed as (AXE. Bound Sword) and my healing spell is listed as (MCE. Healing)... What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have the kinect tuner on.  If you say assign mace or axe it will have that in front of the item you selected.  Try saying equip axe or mace and see if they equip.  If they do then you can just assign something else for them like an actual mace or axe. Just say: assign mace while you hover over the item you want for that slot.